# form variable used for authentication passed to another form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form on a page that redirects to a page where the person must logon. Once their logon is authenticated it returns them to the form to fill out the information. I want the username that they put on the authorization page to be in a hidden field on the form but it isn't passing the variable. I'm thinking it is something in the authentication process.

```
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['snumber'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['snumber'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "xxx.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "sorry.html";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_name, $name);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT snumber, password FROM stverification WHERE snumber=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $pease2) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}

form code:
<input type="hidden" name="snumber" value="<?php echo $_POST['snumber']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

since you set the username in the session, you can use it also on the redirect form like this:

form code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="snumber" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>">
```